# Каково тело фукнции print()?

Tags: python, функции, print

Интересно за счет чего, как текст выводится в терминал.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как вам это поможет,но поскольку у python открытый код, то [вот документация](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c)

```
/*[clinic input]
print as builtin_print
    *args: object
    sep: object(c_default="Py_None") = ' '
        string inserted between values, default a space.
    end: object(c_default="Py_None") = '\n'
        string appended after the last value, default a newline.
    file: object = None
        a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    flush: bool = False
        whether to forcibly flush the stream.
Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
builtin_print_impl(PyObject *module, PyObject *args, PyObject *sep,
                   PyObject *end, PyObject *file, int flush)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=3cfc0940f5bc237b input=c143c575d24fe665]*/
{
    int i, err;




    if (file == Py_None) {
        file = _PySys_GetObjectId(&PyId_stdout);
        if (file == NULL) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "lost sys.stdout");
            return NULL;
        }

        /* sys.stdout may be None when FILE* stdout isn't connected */
        if (file == Py_None) {
            Py_RETURN_NONE;
        }
    }

    if (sep == Py_None) {
        sep = NULL;
    }
    else if (sep && !PyUnicode_Check(sep)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "sep must be None or a string, not %.200s",
                     Py_TYPE(sep)->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (end == Py_None) {
        end = NULL;
    }
    else if (end && !PyUnicode_Check(end)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "end must be None or a string, not %.200s",
                     Py_TYPE(end)->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args); i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            if (sep == NULL) {
                err = PyFile_WriteString(" ", file);
            }
            else {
                err = PyFile_WriteObject(sep, file, Py_PRINT_RAW);
            }
            if (err) {
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        err = PyFile_WriteObject(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, i), file, Py_PRINT_RAW);
        if (err) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    if (end == NULL) {
        err = PyFile_WriteString("\n", file);
    }
    else {
        err = PyFile_WriteObject(end, file, Py_PRINT_RAW);
    }
    if (err) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (flush) {
        PyObject *tmp = _PyObject_CallMethodIdNoArgs(file, &PyId_flush);
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        Py_DECREF(tmp);
    }

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```